# WooCommerce+WP-All-Import - Show stock value in text from linked csv

Tags: php, wordpress, wpallimport

I am testing WP ALL IMPORT plugin to integrate it into my Wordpress.

I already have everything working perfect except one thing.

I import a csv file using link. At the time of showing the stock, I can not because the "stock" field is text type ("high" / "medium" / "low" / "none").

I would like to show it as text in my products. Not as a number.

Is there any way to do it? Maybe with Custom Fields or the PHP Function Editor?

Comment: Do you have paid WP All Import? Then you can do this easily via custom fields under the same while doing product mapping.

Comment: I am testing the paid one in a testing environment that gives the provider to implement it later in my wordpress.
I was trying PHP functions. How does the custom fields work?